# Querying the parent class always returns an empty collection

Tags: inheritance, jdo, datanucleus, discriminator

I have a parent class with the following annotations

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "my_parent_table", objectIdClass = Myclass.PK.class, detachable = "true", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
@Discriminator(strategy = DiscriminatorStrategy.VALUE_MAP, column = "discriminator", value = "0")
```

Now all my child classes have the following annotation, except that the `value` attribute for the `@Discriminator` annotation varies of course and also except for the `table` attribute for the `@PersistanceCapable` annotation.

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true", table = "my_table")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
@Discriminator(value = "1")
```

And through a DAO class, annotated with `@Persistence`, I'm using the following method as a PoC

```
    public List<MyParentClass> test() {
        PersistenceManager pm = null;
        try {
            pm = getPM();
            Query q = pm.newQuery(MyParentClass.class);
            return (List<MyParentClass>) q.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure "Querying the parent class always" executes some SQL, which is visible in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the logs as `DataNucleus` suggested in his comment. I shouldn't have used a `@Discriminator`for the parent class.

I'm not sure if I may use a `@Discriminator` for child classes but I figured a way to drop using it totally for the whole hierarchy so different records for different classes are differentiated by nature.